# Does a drawn Teleportation Circle remain after it has been used?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

Simply put, once a Teleportation Circle drawn for the usage of the spell of the same name has been activated and utilized, does the drawing remain behind? I understand the spell has material components that are required and consumed in the casting of the spell, but it's a bit vague as to whether the drawing is consumed or if it remains behind but is inert.

Example: A party's wizard draws a circle for their home base and the party uses said circle, teleporting them all home. An enemy tracking them finds where the spell was cast and sees the circle left behind, now inert, but easy to replicate with the material components again and cast the spell teleporting the enemy into the party's home base.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 8):

Frankly, this is up to the DM.  The books are silent on whether there is anything left of consumed material components when a spell completes. My assumption would be that while there may be traces left over that could allow a character to determine what spell was cast recently in a location, that would probably not extend to things like determining the exact linked sigil sequence used by a *teleportation circle*.

But as a DM, whether I allow this depends on who's doing it and why, and whether I think letting it happen is a good idea or not.

If the bad guy has used a teleportation circle to escape, I might well allow a canny player to make a very difficult Arcana roll to study the traces and try to make out the sigil sequence the caster used.  If they succeed, then they can begin the process of studying the sigil sequence for 1 minute to commit it to memory for later use. But if the bad guy escaping in this way is meant to be the start of a quest, I'm certainly not going to allow the player to just skip the entire thing and go directly to the end of the adventure by making one good roll. In that case, with a good check, I'd probably let them make out a few of the sigils, a fragmentary result that can give them some clues about where they need to look without giving them the whole answer.

But the situation you describe is the other way around -- the players teleported away, and a villain is following them. I would recommend not doing that. To me it feels like an "Adversarial DM" move; the players have used a spell in the book in the way it was intended to be used, and you are punishing them for doing so. You aren't inflicting consequences of a mistake; there is nothing the party could have reasonably done to avoid this outcome.

If I really wanted to do this, I would probably build a story around it where the party is being pursued by an evil spellcaster, and every time they come into conflict and use *teleport circle* to go home, the villain gets a little closer to figuring out their home sigil pattern. *Eventually*, after great effort, he can show up in their house. I would definitely work to give the party a chance to figure out what's going on -- they need to be aware they're being hunted, and have clues that their use of this spell is dangerous. Perhaps the villain backs off and lets them build their circle when he didn't have to, prompting the party to wonder why he let them go.

Comment: The evil spellcaster can simply scry on the party after they teleport away, and see the teleportation circle runes that way. The party have the option to destroy the circle at their destination if they don't want to be followed, or protect it with Symbol, traps etc.

Comment: @Nick Scry'n'Fry, however it's implemented, is the kind of Adversarial DM tactic that I'm saying you shouldn't do without a lot of setup that alerts the players that it may be incoming.

Answer (score 3):

#### No, the drawn circle is "consumed" when the spell takes effect.

The Material Components section of the Teleportation Circle spell specifies that the rare gem-infused chalks and inks that are used are ***consumed*** by the spell.

Consumed is "consumed". Not "rendered inert" or "deactivated" or "turned to dust" or whatever. Consumed means it's gone.

While it is not 100% written specifically so, it is not a major leap of plain basic common sense to just assume that those rare chalks and inks are exactly what's used to draw the teleportation circle itself. And thus, as they get consumed, as per RAW it means they're fully gone.

Of course, a DM might decide that all materials components, once used up, turn to some kind of dust instead of poof they're fully gone. But as per RAW, consumed material components don't get transmuted into something else, they just wink out. There is not anywhere some kind of specified "consumption" done in a "digestion-like" process that would input "fresh-level magic-usable material components" and output "manure-level magic-unusable material residue". It's not the "somebody eating food and excreting poop" kind of consumption, more like the video game "your character consumed five mana points to cast that spell" kind of consumption. There is nothing left of it.

So, basically, it goes like this:

- Casting: 1 minute, drawing the magic circle with the rare chalks/inks.
- Casting complete: Spell duration begins. The ***material*** components gets consumed, thus the ***material*** circle disappears. However, there is instantly and immediately a ***magical*** luminous version of the same drawn circle that appears to replace it,  seemingly seamlessly.
- At the end of 1 round later: End of spell, thus the magical version of the circle also disappears.

Exception: If you cast the spell every day for 1 year, the last casting is not 1 round duration, but Permanent duration.

Now, that last past seems to imply that there is some kind of "counter" thing going on, ***almost*** as if as the spell left over some kind of ***residual*** magical energy left over in that spot. Or somehow the universe itself "remembers" what you did in that spot or gets "imprinted" somehow.

So, now, it all depends on how your DM ***interprets*** this last part. He might go two ways:

1. Nope, no weird unexplained "after effect" magical residual traces.
   Once the spell ends, it's gone, end of story. The fact that repeated
   castings eventually make the last casting permanent doesn't specify
   any such "residual magics" or "universal memory or imprint" in RAW,
   so there is none. The spell itself seemingly goes to check the past,
   and that's it. Pursuers thus detect nothing special. This is a DM
   "playing it safe and by the book".
2. Hmm, DM decides that yeah, there is some kind of magical residual
   "leftover aura" or ***whatever***, lasting at least until the next
   casting the next day, so that there can eventually be some kind of
   "cumulative" effect to stack up enough magical power there, to allow
   the last casting 1 year later to be done on a sufficiently powerful
   "mass" of "accumulated" magical residue, to power "enough" the last
   casting so that it become permanent instead. Thus the DM gives a
   chance for pursuers to detect something. This is a fully arbitrary
   DM call and ruling. Maybe a simple Detect Magic is enough to readily
   see it. Maybe you also need See Invisibility because "residual
   magics" are so weak they are invisible to sight EVEN with Detect
   Magic. Maybe a Perception check is needed too. Maybe a special
   magical item is needed to see "residual magical auras". Maybe True
   Seeing is a must. Any of these, or a combo of some or all of these,
   or some great divinatory process or whatever your DM might come up
   with after smoking some way too good stuff. Whatever. This is a DM
   using RAW to spin a cool (but not necessarily wisely built) story.

Personally, I am big fan of Option #2. :-)

---

Edit for all the nitpickers:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consume

Consume: 1st meaning found: "To do away with completely DESTROY".

Can't be clearer and simpler than that!
RAW the book uses the word consumed, and dictionary definition of the word says
completely destroyed as 1st meaning found.

RAW the word consumed appear often and just repeating the spell itself seemed pretty useless to me but here goes anyway:

https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Teleportation%20Circle#content

> Components: V M (Rare chalks and inks infused with precious gems with
> 50 gp, which the spell consumes)

And In the chapter 10 on magic, components section:

> If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell,
> the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell.

Again, the actual *absence*  of a rule on "stuff winks out", only again the use of the word "consumed", thus, not really worth writing expressly. We should think that readers aren't *that* stupid.

So, again, per RAW, zero clear indication to specify that *nothing* remains. But also zero clear indication that *something* remains, either. In which case, like the "RAW" I invoked, then we don't invent imaginary stuff and just use basic english 1st accepted definition of the word "consume.

Just what was so crazy debatable and complicated to understand about that point? I wonder.

Comment: Things can be consumed and still leave waste. That’s one of the main problems with our consumer economy. Consumed means “used up”, not “destroyed”.

Comment: Yeah, in the real world "consumed" generally means "used up with leftover waste". Not so in game worlds, D&D or otherwise, where consumed usually means "utterly destroyed and fully gone" and is closer in meaning to "spending a resource".

Comment: @Pat citation please

Comment: What I don't like about this answer is that you use *"RAW"* a lot but actually never write out any rules and it ends up looking a lot like just your opinion. Moreover, your reading of the word consumed is fairly specific – "Large amount of wood is consumed daily to make paper." ...seems like a normal sentence to me. Does this mean that the wood simply vanishes? No, it's transformed into paper. Just as material components are – in this case – transformed into a magic circle. Doesn't mean it's all going to disappear, IMHO.

Comment: My issue here is with your assumption about the word *consumed*. When my daughter draws on the sidewalk the chalk is *consumed*, and as far as I know she's no wizard. This answer doesn't make clear why *consumed* means anything more than it does when my daughter draws on the sidewalk.

Comment: It seems like the edit to this answer does little more than claim that Merriam-Webster, as opposed to any other dictionary, should be the one of choice for interpreting the 5e rules. And the concluding admission that there is "no clear indication" to support this rules interpretation directly contradicts multiple statements earlier in the answer which make claims about RAW.

Comment: @ recognizer : Opposed to what dictionary? I used webster = 1st google hit. But if you did your homework before nitpicking you'd have seen: Google itself has consume at 3rd definition also to utterly destroy. Next is Cambridge dictionary: same thing: utterly destroy is a valid definition. Then it is dictionary.com: same thing, 1st definition here too. Then it is Collins, then Lexico, ... all the same! etc.! RAW = just use the exact RAW word used (consume), thus use it's dictionary accepted definition (most uses fit better than the "eating" one). I'm not the one going personal opinions here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer edit V2blast, great cleanup work.

Answer (score 1):

### *Teleportation Circle* probably doesn't leave a readable trace

The DMG has a section on [teleportation circles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/a-world-of-your-own#TeleportationCircles), which provides some relevant information on how they fit in to the world:

> The presence of permanent teleportation circles in major cities helps cement their important place in the economy of a fantasy world. Spells such as *plane shift*, *teleport*, and *teleportation circle* connect with these circles, which are found in temples, academies, the headquarters of arcane organizations, and prominent civic locations. However, since every teleportation circle is a possible means of entry into a city, they’re guarded by military and magical protection.

From this, we see that permanent teleportation circles are objects of major economic and military significance (not to mention the significant financial investment required to create one). This means that a circle's unique sigil sequence must be a closely guarded secret, revealed to only those with the proper authorization to use the circle.

If the *teleportation circle* spell left enough of its material component behind to allow someone to read the sigil sequence it was cast with, this would make it nearly impossible to keep the sigil sequence a secret. Hence, while never specified explicitly, the lore quoted above from the DMG strongly implies that the spell is designed in such a way that the sigil sequence can't be learned simply by looking at the site where the spell was cast after the fact. (In fact, we might speculate that the spell was intentionally designed to consume its material component for exactly this reason.)

As to whether the spell leaves any trace at all that it was cast, that's entirely up to the DM. In practice, I believe a common ruling is to allow an Arcana check to determine that the spell was cast.

### A permanent teleportation circle is probably readable

From the spell's text:

> Many major temples, guilds, and other important places have permanent teleportation circles inscribed somewhere within their confines. Each such circle includes a unique sigil sequence--a string of magical runes arranged in a particular pattern. When you first gain the ability to cast this spell, you learn the sigil sequences for two destinations on the Material Plane, determined by the GM. You can learn additional sigil sequences during your adventures. You can commit a new sigil sequence to memory after studying it for 1 minute.

This specifies that a permanent teleportation circle is inscribed, and that the circle's inscription includes its unique sigil sequence. This means that the inscription of the sigil sequence should be visible to anyone who can see the circle.